# how to create an order log in google sheet using google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exnDw.png)

I have 2 tables:

- The table on the left-hand side has 5 lines of order for 5 customers.
- The table on the right-hand side is the order history made by the 5 customers.

My goal is to track every order that the customers `submitted` or `Updated` without overwriting the previous row of orders in the order history table when the customers are submitting or updating their orders.

For example, when the first customer subitted his order, it will be shown in the first row of the order history table. When the 4th customer submitted his order, it will be shown in the 2nd row of the order history table instead of 4th row. Then, if the 1st customer want to update his order after the 4th customer submitted his order, the updated order will be shown in the 3rd row of the order history table instead of overwriting the first row.

I'm very new to google apps script and this is what I had tried:

```
function onEdit(e){

  const time = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'Asia/Singapore', 'HH:mm:ss');


  if (e.range.columnStart == 6 && e.range.rowStart >= 4) {
    if (e.value == 'Update' || e.value == 'Submit') {

      const order = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1).getValue();
      const type  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart, 2).getValue();
      const food = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart, 3).getValue();
      const price = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart, 4).getValue();
      const quantity = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart, 5).getValue();
      const status = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart, 6).getValue();

      e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(time);
      e.range.offset(0, 3).setValue(order);
      e.range.offset(0, 4).setValue(type);
      e.range.offset(0, 5).setValue(food);
      e.range.offset(0, 6).setValue(price);
      e.range.offset(0, 7).setValue(quantity);
      e.range.offset(0, 8).setValue(status);
      e.range.offset(0, 9).setValue(time);

    } else {
      e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue('');
    }
  } 
}
```

I know that I need to `getLastrow` to print the data but I'm not sure how to include it in my code. I attached my google sheet here for your reference:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cFH1oZVzu9SCqrHc9IQskaKoBMLIfLG6azc7vCCxLlg/edit?usp=sharing

Any help or advice will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Any experts have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You might not need `getLastRow`. I.E. you might use:

- `SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.appendRow(rowContents)` to add data on the first empty row below the data range.
- `SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getDataRange()` to read the sheet data range (from A1 to the last column and last row having content)

Best practices summary:

Try to minimize the number of calls to the Google Apps Script classes and methods as they are relatively slow, i.e. instead of multiple getRange to read single consecutive cells use one to read a range that encompse all of them, if the cells aren't consecutive you might use `SpradsheetApp.Sheet.getRangeList(references)`

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices

Comment: It is really hard for me to figuring out how to use `SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.appendRow(rowContents)` & `SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getDataRange()` in my current script without further guidance as I'm really new in this. Wish that you can give further advise.

Comment: Hi there @desmond! In these links you can find more information about [`Sheet.appendRow()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=en#appendrowrowcontents) and [`Sheet.getDataRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=en#getdatarange). If you still need help after checking that documentation, don't hesitate to write back about your doubts.

Comment: It's worthy to highlight that both link include  code snippets

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e){
  const dt = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'Asia/Singapore', 'HH:mm:ss');
  if (e.range.columnStart == 6 && e.range.rowStart >= 4) {
    if (e.value == 'Update' || e.value == 'Submit') {
      e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(dt);
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet ();
      var source = ss.getRange ("A4:G4");
      var direction = SpreadsheetApp.Direction
      var aLast = ss.getRange("I"+(ss.getLastRow()+1)).getNextDataCell(direction.UP).getRow()
      var destRange = ss.getRange(aLast+1,9);
      source.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
    } else {
      e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue('');
    }
  } 
}
```

This is the solution that works for me, in case future readers would like to know.